# division by zero program crash in c++

Tags: c++

Can any body tells me what are the reasons of program crash when somebody divide some thing by  zero in c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best "reason" is that, per the language, division by zero is undefined behavior, so anything could happen. A crash is the most useful "anything" to the programmer since it helps you catch the bug.

As for why the C++ language left division by zero undefined, that probably comes from C which does the same, and in turn from the facts that (1) there is no mathematical definition, and (2) different hardware might do different things when dividing by zero, and since there's no reason a valid program should be making the division by zero, it's not worth adding an emulation/patch-up layer around every division to force a common behavior on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Division by zero is **mathematically** undefined, it has nothing to do with c++ or any other language.

Comment: -1: Some languages will define `x/0` in a non-crash way (try Javascript if you want). In any case it's the language that defines what operators do, so this has everything to do with the language you are programming in.

Comment: @trinithis What? I said **nothing** about crashing. I said division by zero is mathematically undefined (which is true). Every programming language i know evaluates it as undefined (either directly named as such or +/-inf which is also mathematically undefined).

Comment: Okay then, well it still does not come close to answering the OP's question. (The last sentence of my first comment is the relevant one anyway.)